# How to debug CrashDump of ASP.NET 4.5 - symbols mismatch / missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.5, missing-symbols

Having sporadic w3wp.exe crashes on productive system

**Neither way of debugging the CrashDump using WinDbg or VisualStudio2012 was successful**

**VS2012**:  Debugging information for w3wp.exe cannot be found or does not match.
No symbols loaded for System.Web.ni.dll - No matching binary found.
OurOwnCustom.dll: No matching binary found

**WinDbg**:  PSSCOR4 not supporting .NET 4.5
StackTraces not showing managed server code at all

**How should we debug ASP.NET 4.5 CrashDumps successfully?**

Or is this currently not possible due to missing public symbols for .NET 4.5?